# Converting a GUID to System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat

Tags: .net, imaging, system.drawing.imaging

I store information about images in a database - also their ImageFormat (jpeg, png etc).

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);  

Outputs: b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e
```

I want to store this in the database as a GUID - and read from the database and get the associated ImageFormat.

How do I cast the GUID 
b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e 
to
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid
?

Comment: store GUID in a database :) instead of JPEG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide a [System.Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) to the [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)'s [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.imageformat.aspx), and you can read it back using it's [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.guid.aspx) property.

A System.Guid has several [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.guid.aspx), including a [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) constructor.

Answer (score 1):

1) store GUID in a database instead of JPEG

2) use constructor:

```
ImageFormat(
    Guid guid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't [ImageFormat's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.imageformat.aspx) let you get the ImageFormat by its Guid?